# "Event is not defined" error message is showing when I try to open email client using dblclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 email input fields with a class name of `send_email`. I want to show a email client when the user double clicks on an email field. To do that I am using the following jQuery code but it's showing an error message:

> event is not defined

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.send_mail').dblclick(function() {
    event.preventDefault();    
    var email = $(this).val();
    var subject = '';    
    window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject;
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('input.send_mail').dblclick(function(event) {`, you need to accept `event` as an parameter to the handler

Answer (score 2):

In your `dblclick` code you use `event.preventDefault()`, yet haven't set the event property. Try this:

```
$('input.send_mail').dblclick(function(event) { // < 'event' here
    event.preventDefault();   
    // your code...
}):
```